# Editing 2D arrays to display a "map"

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

So, I'm doing a "map overlay" for a 2D array in Javascript, but it keeps coming out like this:

Have a Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/HcRVW/6/

Note that the map is being rendered in some strange order.

Cheers in advance, I've been looking at it for ages now.

```
<html>  
<head>
<title>tileEngine - Isometric</title>
<style type="text/css">
#mapoverlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 888;
    top: 70px;
    color: lightgreen;
    width: 420px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-opacity:.50;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity:.50;
    background-color: #666;
    z-index: 900;
    -moz-text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000;
}
.mN { width: 8px; height: 8px; display: inline-block; float: right; list-style-type: none; background-color: #fff; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var map = Array( //land
    [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
    [2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2],
    [2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2],
    [2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
    [2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
    [2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
    [2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
    [2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2],
    [2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2],
    [2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
    [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
);

    for(i=0;i<map.length;i++){
        for(a=0;a<map[i].length;a++){
            $('#mapoverlay').append('<li class="mN '+map[i][a]+'">&nbsp;</li>');
        }
    }
    $('.mN').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('0')) {
            $(this).css({'background-color':'green'})
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('1')) {
            $(this).css({'background-color':'blue'})
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('2')) {
            $(this).css({'background-color':'blue'})
        } else  {
            $(this).css({'background-color':'green'})
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head> 
<body align="center" style="text-align: center;">    
        <ul id="mapoverlay"></ul>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Could you update your fiddle to use the appropriate fields for HTML, CSS and JS? Currently it's not nice to read since you have to scroll a lot.

Comment: Unrelated but very important: Always use `for(var i=0;i<map.length;i++){` instead of `for(i=0;i<map.length;i++){`. Otherwise your loop variable is **global**, causing problems when e.g. calling a function in your loop that also contains a `for(i=...)` loop.

Comment: @Thief: Or better yet, declare it at the top of the function (which is where the declaration actually is regardless of where you put `var`).

Comment: @Neuro: Live examples are a great *adjunct* to the question, but please always put the relevant code *in the question*. External links can be modified, deleted, moevd... StackOverflow is meant to stand alone, and to be useful to other people after you.

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers on how to use the site... Any ideas on my issue though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your css. See you have 57 items per array. That is 57x8=456px.

```
#mapoverlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 888;
    top: 70px;
    color: lightgreen;
    width: 456px;
    border: 10px solid #666;
    -moz-opacity:.50;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity:.50;
    background-color: #666;
    z-index: 900;
    -moz-text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.mN { width: 8px; height: 8px; display: block; float: left; list-style-type: none; background-color: #fff; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/HcRVW/9/

Removed the fancy CSS stuff and updated the width to hold same amount of items as each "inner" array length.

Also separated HTML, JS and CSS as jsFiddle supports it.

Comment: Almost, your math is slightly out

Answer (score 0):

Heloo,
i saw the fiddle example and i think u have to decrease the array size
or increase overlay size.

because i tried to decrease the array size like this `http://jsfiddle.net/HcRVW/10/`

Answer (score 0):

Two off-topic points (hence this being a CW answer):

1. `0`, `1`, and `2` are invalid CSS classes. In CSS, a class name [must not start with a digit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier).
2. Rather than calling `Array` as a function, recommend just using literal notation throughout as you have with the sub-arrays, e.g.:

   ```
   var map = [
       [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2, // ...
   ];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here. Seems they do the same, but transforming to 3D also:
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/creating-pseudo-3d-games-with-html-5-can-1/